# YOLOv3 vehicles Detection using Polylines to detect the slots area

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, opencv, yolov8, python

I would trying to detect vehicles (car, bus, truck, motorcycle, bicycle) using YOLOv3, I used the same task with YOLOv8 and I got a good results what I made is that I draw a polylines for the slots area and choose to detect in this area using YOLOv8 but when I tried to implement the same on YOLOv3 it doesn't work

This is the code for YOLOv3 without implementing the polylines

```
# Importing needed libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2

# initialize minimum probability to eliminate weak predictions
p_min = 0.5

# threshold when applying non-maxia suppression
thres = 0.

# 'VideoCapture' object and reading video from a file
video = cv2.VideoCapture('parking1.mp4')

# Preparing variable for writer
# that we will use to write processed frames
writer = None

# Preparing variables for spatial dimensions of the frames
h, w = None, None

# Create labels into list
with open('coco.names') as f:
    labels = [line.strip() for line in f]
# Initialize colours for representing every detected object
colours = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(labels), 3), dtype='uint8')

# Loading trained YOLO v3 Objects Detector
# with the help of 'dnn' library from OpenCV
# Reads a network model stored in Darknet model files.
network = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3.cfg',
                                     'yolov3.weights')

# Getting only output layer names that we need from YOLO
ln = network.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i- 1] for i in network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

# Defining loop for catching frames
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Getting dimensions of the frame for once as everytime dimensions will be same
    if w is None or h is None:
        # Slicing and get height, width of the image
        h, w = frame.shape[:2]

    # frame preprocessing for deep learning
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
                                 swapRB=True, crop=False)

    # perform a forward pass of the YOLO object detector, giving us our bounding boxes
    # and associated probabilities.
    network.setInput(blob)
    output_from_network = network.forward(ln)

    # Preparing lists for detected bounding boxes, confidences and class numbers.
    bounding_boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_numbers = []

    # Going through all output layers after feed forward pass
    for result in output_from_network:
        for detected_objects in result:
            scores = detected_objects[5:]
            class_current = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence_current = scores[class_current]

            if confidence_current > p_min:
                box_current = detected_objects[0:4] * np.array([w, h, w, h])

                # Now, from YOLO data format, we can get top left corner coordinates
                # that are x_min and y_min
                x_center, y_center, box_width, box_height = box_current
                x_min = int(x_center - (box_width / 2))
                y_min = int(y_center - (box_height / 2))

                # Adding results into prepared lists
                bounding_boxes.append([x_min, y_min, int(box_width), int(box_height)])
                confidences.append(float(confidence_current))
                class_numbers.append(class_current)

    # Implementing non-maximum suppression of given bounding boxes
    # With this technique we exclude some of bounding boxes if their
    # corresponding confidences are low or there is another
    # bounding box for this region with higher confidence
    results = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bounding_boxes, confidences,
                               p_min, thres)

    # At-least one detection should exists
    if len(results) > 0:
        for i in results.flatten():
            # Getting current bounding box coordinates, its width and height
            x_min, y_min = bounding_boxes[i][0], bounding_boxes[i][1]
            box_width, box_height = bounding_boxes[i][2], bounding_boxes[i][3]

            # Preparing colour for current bounding box
            colour_box_current = colours[class_numbers[i]].tolist()

            # Drawing bounding box on the original image
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x_min, y_min),
                          (x_min + box_width, y_min + box_height),
                          colour_box_current, 2)

            # Preparing text with label and confidence for current bounding box
            text_box_current = '{}: {:.4f}'.format(labels[int(class_numbers[i])],
                                                   confidences[i])

            # Putting text with label and confidence on the original image
            cv2.putText(frame, text_box_current, (x_min, y_min - 5),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, colour_box_current, 2)

    """Store proccessed frames into result video."""
    # Initialize writer
    if writer is None:
        resultVideo = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4')

        # Writing current processed frame into the video file
        #writer = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4', resultVideo, 48,
                                 #(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), True)
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter('video1.mp4',fourcc, 30.0, (1300, 765))
        #int fourcc , double 60, Size 1920*1080, bool isColor = true
    # Write processed current frame to the file
    writer.write(frame)

# Releasing video reader and writer
video.release()
writer.release()
```

This is the Kaggle notebook for YOLOv8 using input video to detect the cars and count them:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/maryamkhaled/2-parking-area-yolov8